# error: macro "assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1

Tags: c++

```
vector<string> foo(vector<string> s) { return s; }
assert(foo(vector<string>{"hello", "world"}) ==
         vector<string>{"hello", "world"});
```

- error: macro "assert" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
- error: ‘assert’ was not declared in this scope

maybe define assert in gcc 11.1.0

```
#  define assert(expr)                          \
     (static_cast <bool> (expr)                     \
      ? void (0)                            \
      : __assert_fail (#expr, __FILE__, __LINE__, __ASSERT_FUNCTION))
```

compiler flag is

```
 -Wall -std=c++20
```

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor only has a primitive understanding of C++'s syntax, and in particular it sees any commas not enclosed in parentheses as argument separators. There are two commas in your `assert` call, and only one is enclosed in parentheses, so the macro thinks it's getting two arguments as follows

```
foo(vector<string>{"hello", "world"}) == vector<string>{"hello"
"world"});
```

Wrap the expression in parentheses to prevent this.

```
// Note: Double parens
assert((foo(vector<string>{"hello", "world"}) ==
        vector<string>{"hello", "world"}));
```